# background-attachment: fixed flickers in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I tried google for help on this and it seems to be a bug in chrome but I still can't find a solution. I have taken a look at many stackoverflow questions similar to this but those solutions still didn't help.

When I try to scroll down on the page the background-image flickers and messes up. I am using Google Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 on Ubuntu Desktop

CSS code:

```
#left-container {
background-image: url('http://easource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/traphouse4.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: -1% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can see how it looks on http://easource.com

Also, I tried removing the background-position but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property/value `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the element that is flickering in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I added that line but that still didn't have an affect on the page.

Comment: Is there anything else that might work that I should give a try?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, add a positive `z-index` to your #left-container and #right-container elements.

```
z-index: 101;
```

Also be sure to remove the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` or it will not work.

Sorry for the double answer; I can't post 'comments' until I have more reputation.

Comment: Strange.. When I add z-index:101; to the two containers in Chrome's Developer Tools, it works just fine. I am fully updated to chrome 36 though.

Comment: Alternatively, you can remove the fixed positioning.